# Is it possible to create a G-Suite application for Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to figure out is there a way to create and publish a G-Suite application for Google Calendar.

I see that the category "Works with Calendar" https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-calendar contains only some applications for video conferencing and I couldn't find any info on how to create a similar application.

I have a web service and would like to allow users to add a link to its specific page when they create an event. Just like the video conferencing does.

Does anybody know if it is possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, see https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-calendar. However, publishing calendar add-ons is not open to the general public yet. A Google Partner can request the Calendar team to be whitelisted.

Comment: Thanks, Alejandro. Do you know how to contact the Calendar team?

Comment: Customer wishes to be part of this beta, then they can sign up through the "Express interest" link on this page:
https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/04/gsuite-add-ons-beta.html
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeGZmRs3N2qAHY7NCTXLHZEI8cNNtUNzMATKcEbyThaN8gY6A/viewform